# MongoDb c# converting document into object

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to get list of documents by the filter, which is returning posts that have categoryId=1. Im not sure how to make this work:

```
public List<Post> getAllProgramming() 
    {
        var result = new List<Post>();

        var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("SearchForKnowledge");
        var coll = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Posts");

        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("CategoryId", 1);
        result = coll.Find(filter).ToList<Post>;
    }
```

Everything is fine, except for the last line of the code, the conversion is not valid. What should be the solution to this? Thank you in advance and have a nice Friday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as following...

```
public List<Post> getAllProgramming() 
{
    var result = new List<Post>();

    var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
    var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("SearchForKnowledge");
    var coll = database.GetCollection<Post>("Posts");

    var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(p => p.CategoryId, 1);
    result = coll.Find(filter).ToList();
}
```